# how does MVVM with a child MVVM work in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, design-patterns, mvvm

Suppose I have ViewController A, its viewModel AVM. A has a containerView, which is ViewController B and its viewModel BVM. A has reference of B and AVM has a reference of BVM as its child View Model.

And I have a C, which is a manager class controls the behaviour of B, calling functions in B such as setSDImage(url) from B.

B has a UIImageView and has setSDImage(url) function with a callback. A has a button, when button pressed, it *should trigger* the setSDImage(url) for B.

So the problems is: Press button from A, goes to AVM, then AVM contacts C telling it to do some work to B, now, C has to get a reference of B since the function call is setSDImage(url) which is UI layer. Also, the callback needs to be implemented in B as well, that's why I don't know how to get this work in BVM rather than B.

So, questions in this case:

1, manager class C, controls behaviour of B. How does AVM contact C without passing reference of B? (since VM don't want to know about ViewControllers/views)

2, should manager class C controls B or BVM? I make it controls B instead of BVM because a) the set image function has to be done in UILayer which is B. b) the callback needs to be implemented in UILayer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit hard to understand what's going on just from your description, but I would say that a method called `setSDImage` which takes a URL doesn't belong in the view controller, since then the view controller needs to do the work of downloading the image data, converting it to a `UIImage` and then setting that on a `UIImagView`.

Downloading the image and converting it is work that should be initiated by `BVM` which then notifies `B` when the `UIImage` is ready.

So, to answer your second question, I think `C` should have a reference to `BVM`, which should be easy for `AVM`.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Thx for the reply. I am using the SDWebImage library for downloading image. And their function is ```[imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/olivier.poitrey/picture"]
             placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"avatar-placeholder.png"]
                      options:SDWebImageRefreshCached];```. which means I should be doing it in the view controller. Because it is directly set to UIImageView but not UIImage.

Comment: I'm not a fan of those kinds of extensions on `UIView`. Technically, the code is not implemented in the view, but it's attaching that behavior to the view, so to me it feels like a violation of MVC and MVVM. However, you can still follow the same pattern but passing the URL instead of the UIImage. The key to MVVM is that the VC can communicate directly with the VM, but the VM only communicates with the VC indirectly through a protocol, or KVO, or whatever notification mechanism you wish.